# Wifi disconnecting while downloading file

Tags: networking, wireless, kernel, realtek-wireless, wifi-direct

I have a problem - while downloading files through WiFi, in the middle WiFi disconnects and I get this message:

```
RTL871X: rtw_cmd_thread: DriverStopped(0) SurpriseRemoved(1) break at line 507
[sched_delayed] sched: RT throttling activated
```

Here is the Log

```
#iwconfig wlan0 essid "Test"  
RTL871X: nolinked power save leave        
RTL871X: set ssid [Test] fw_state=0x00000008  
#  
# RTL871X: start auth RTL871X: auth success, start assoc RTL871X: indicate disassoc


# wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -B 
rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device RTL871X: nolinked power save leave
RTL871X: set bssid:00:00:00:00:00:00 ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not
permitted1X: set ssid [g�isQ�J�)ͺ����F|�T���vZ.c3�ɚ]
fw_state=0x00000008

RTL871X: indicate disassoc RTL871X: set ssid [Test] fw_state=0x00000008 RTL871X: set bssid:84:c9:b2:2a:97:92 RTL871X:
start auth RTL871X: auth success, start assoc RTL871X: assoc success
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready RTL871X:
send eapol packet RTL871X: send eapol packet RTL871X: set pairwise
key camid:4, addr:84:c9:b2:2a:97:92, kid:0, type:TKIP RTL871X: set
group key camid:5, addr:84:c9:b2:2a:97:92, kid:2, type:TKIP

 # udhcpc -i wlan0 udhcpc (v1.20.2) started Sending discover... Sending discover... Sending discover...

Sending discover... Sending discover... Sending select for
192.168.0.107... Lease of 192.168.0.107 obtained, lease time 86400 deleting routers route: SIOCDELRT: No such process adding dns
192.168.0.1
# 
# 
# 
# ping 8.8.8.8 
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes 
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=56 time=24.468 ms 
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=56 time=174.437 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics --- 3 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 33% packet loss round-trip min/avg/max =
24.468/99.452/174.437 ms

# curl ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-1.42.tar.gz -k >2MB_19071   
% Total  % Received % Xferd  Average Speed  Time  Time   Time  current
                              Dload  Upload Total Spent  Left    Speed  
19 1817k 19  346k    0     0   8197    0   0:03:46 0:00:43 0:03:03  0        
RTL871X: rtw_cmd_thread: DriverStopped(0) SurpriseRemoved(1) break at line 507
[sched_delayed] sched: RT throttling activated
19 1817k 19  346k    0     0   7497    0  0:04:08 0:00:47 0:03:21   0  
19 1817k 19  346k    0     0   7340    0  0:04:13 0:00:48 0:03:25   0
```

From Here Download stops. running processes are

```
#ps   
661 root     [RTW_XMIT_THREAD]   
662 root     [RTW_CMD_THREAD]   
663 root     [RTWHALXT-wlan0]   
673 root     wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -B   
682 root     udhcpc -i wlan0   
685 root     ps
```

Here what is RT throttling? What's happening and how can I fix it?
If you need any other information, please give comment i will share.

Comment: Start here https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Answer (score 1):

Real Time throttling means there is a real-time task(s) that are consuming significant amounts of network bandwidth. At some point the system will throttle the connection down in an attempt to keep the system functioning.  In this case, the culprit is likely the app you are using to transfer files with.  Could just need a little tweaking in preferences.

This could be why you are dropping your wifi connection.

Your second question on how to connect and disconnect wifi has many very good answers already in the knowledge base.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Here I am not intentionally dropping Wi-Fi connection.  While downloading in the middle getting this error and download stops. What may be the issue ? with kernel or Driver ? or any other thing to modify ? How to start solving this issue ?

Comment: I didn't read your question as intentionally dropping the connection.  It could be that the driver is doing it's job by throttling back the connection.  Or perhaps you have the wrong driver or an old driver.  Lots of info here on how to check and fix those things.  What app(s) are you using to download these files and do you have more than one session running.  For example, running several instances of Filezilla or going multiple, simultaneous wgets of sftp's might cause these symptoms.

Comment: please once observe the log. I am downloading only one file using curl.